How to capture ProxyPassMatch response?
I have an apache proxy server setup that acts as a router between my multiple backends. The httpd.conf file is something like this
ProxyPassMatch "something/([^/]*)/(.*)" "http://$1/$2"
Pretty straightforward, if the URL matches, then redirect to the target, which is just a concat of the matches.
My question is, I'd like to redirect one more time if the original proxy 404s. So say the URL matches on this line and it gets redirected to the target, and it 404s, I want to be able to send the request to a default target.
So far I have tried using RewriteCond and RewriteRule:
# my original ProxyPassMatch rule
ProxyPassMatch "something/([^/]*)/(.*)" "http://$1/$2"

# enable
RewriteEngine On

# the condition I am looking for on any previous ProxyPassMatch rules
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =404

# if the RewriteCond evaulates to true, do this rule and be done:
RewriteRule "some_regex" "http://default/$1" [P,L]

Some information here is from ChatGPT and figured it was incorrect, but haven't been able to confirm.
Is this even possible? What is the best way to achieve this?
New to the whole apache/proxy world so any help would be great!

To clarify, the original request and the proxied request are all handled by the same server? What determines the 404? Simply that the request does not map to a physical file (or directory) or is the 404 determined by some other server-side application?

The original request hits this apache proxy server which then redirects it to another server, lets say called s1, which is where a FastAPI app sits. If this 404s, then the original apache server should redirect the request to another default server called lets say d1. So try s1 and if 404, then go hit d1.
